# Completely incorrect tax calculation

Tags: checkout, cart, price, tax

On our Magento installation we have created a new shopping cart price rule that gives a 20 EUR discount amount for the whole cart:

[image: shopping cart price rule]

After that we have double checked the tax settings to make sure that the following happens:

1. Discount is applied on the price excluding tax
2. Tax is calculated after the discount has been applied

[image: tax settings]

When that's was done we added a product to the shopping basket. This product has a price excl tax of 80 EUR. (Including tax: 96.60 EUR):

[image: cart with wrong tax calculation]

Our findings:
 - Subtotal = correct

- Discount amount = correct
- Grand total excl tax = **incorrect**
- Tax = **incorrect**
- Grand total = **incorrect**

**So basically this means that Magento does not take the setting "Apply Customer tax" into consideration? Anyone also came across this problem? Any help on what the correct way would be to fix this?**

Comment: EE 1.13 has lots of tax fixes, unfortunately CE 1.8 has them as well but is not out yet.

Comment: I tried this on EE 1.13 also and the same issue is happening. Magento always considers the discount incl tax and that's why these weird totals are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed on 1.8 CE Alpha - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes#ce18-1800tax-round

> Specifying that prices display in the web store excluding tax and
>   setting a 20% tax rate (or discount rate) now calculates the grand
>   total correctly.

As this was a known issue and 1.8 is in Alpha at the moment, it can stand to reason that once 1.8CE goes gold these changes roll up into 1.13EE in a minor version update.